# "error in axis" for Boxplot in R

Tags: r, boxplot

I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in axis(side = 1, at = 1:3, labels = c("ADDA", "DM")) : 
  'at' and 'labels' lengths differ, 3 != 2
```

when running

```
boxplot(ELISA_Mussel$conc2~ELISA_Mussel$ELISA,main="ELISA",
    names=c("ADDA","DM"),
    ylab=expression(paste(mu,"g/L")))
```

although I only have 2 labels. Why does it say that I have 3? The data (ELISA_Mussel) looks like this:

```
ELISA   conc2
ADDA    20
ADDA    11.5
ADDA    18.5
ADDA    16.5
ADDA    17.6
ADDA    20
ADDA    11.5
ADDA    20
ADDA    14.5
ADDA    20
ADDA    8.5
ADDA    10.5
DM  6
DM  3.9
DM  4.3
DM  4.6
DM  5
DM  3.6
DM  6.2
DM  7
DM  3.8
DM  3.2
DM  5.4
DM  6.8
ADDA    8.6
ADDA    6.9
ADDA    3.9
ADDA    2.2
ADDA    7.4
ADDA    3.7
ADDA    4.5
ADDA    13.2
ADDA    8.6
ADDA    9.2
DM  1.6
DM  0.01
DM  0.01
DM  0.01
DM  0.01
DM  0.01
DM  0.01
DM  0.01
DM  1.6
DM  1.5
```

`str(ELISA_Mussel)`

'data.frame':   64 obs. of  15 variables:

$ ELISA     : Factor w/ 3 levels "","ADDA","DM": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Seafood   : Factor w/ 2 levels "","Mussel": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Method    : Factor w/ 3 levels "","LongMeOH",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ conc      : Factor w/ 32 levels "","

Comment: So your data is not too big, please paste the output of `dput(ELISA_Mussel[c("ELISA", "conc2")])`.

Answer (score 1):

You must have a factor with three levels, although only two are used. You can check by doing:

```
is.factor(ELISA_Mussel$ELISA)
# TRUE
nlevels(ELISA_Mussel$ELISA)
# [1] 3
```

You can fix that by dropping unused levels:

```
ELISA_Mussel$ELISA <- droplevels(ELISA_Mussel$ELISA)
```

Then it should plot fine.

In fact, you don't even have to modify your data if you use `droplevels` in the `boxplot` formula:

```
boxplot(ELISA_Mussel$conc2 ~ droplevels(ELISA_Mussel$ELISA),
        main="ELISA", ylab=expression(paste(mu,"g/L")))
```

(Also note that you can leave the `names` option alone since levels are used by default.)

Comment: @flodel-I don't understand why I have a factor with 3 levels-when I am only listing 2. I have tried moving the data to another spreadsheet, but can't seem to get rid of this 3rd level. Also if you have an idea on how to get rid of the extra (tic mark) (comment below) it would be helpful

Comment: When I tried the droplevels in the boxplot code it plotted, but I still have an extra factor (tic mark) on the x axis

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help more without a reproducible example. If your data is not too big, you could provide the output of `dput(ELISA_Mussel)`. If not, maybe `str(ELISA_Mussel)` can be useful. Please add that info as an edit to your question.

Comment: You have a `""` level which explains the extra boxplot with just a tickmark. You really ought to cleanup your data.